# Call parent class's function with *args and **kwds in python

Tags: python, inheritance

I think following code should print `a\n('b')\n{'a':1}`. But, actually it print "a\n('b', {'a': 1})\n{}" Why? I checked these [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972866/correct-way-to-use-super-argument-passing) and seems my code does not have problems.

```
class Parent(object):
    def f(self, a, *args, **kwargs):
        print a
        print args
        print kwargs

class Child(Parent):
    def f(self, a, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child, self).f(a, *args, **kwargs)

c = Child()
c.f("a", "b", {"a":1})
```

Comment: Typo: `Chi` should be `Child`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected output. You seem to think that your dictionary should be treated as a keyword argument. It's not, it's also a positional argument like b.

A keyword argument `akw` would be called like this:

```
 f("a", "b", akw=1):
      # your code
```