# How to call constructor from superclass

Tags: python, oop

```
class User(object):

    def __init__(self, id_code, name, surname):
        self.id_code = id_code
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

class Worker(User):

    def __init__(self, username, password, worker_type):
        super(User, self).__init__()
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.worker_type = worker_type
```

How i can call constructor with attributes from super class?

ex:

```
id_code = "test_code"
name = "test_name"
surname = "test_surname"
username = "test_username"
password = "test_pass"
```

Comment: You need to name *your own class*, not the super class, in `super()`:         `super(Worker, self).__init__()`. You also need to pass in the expected arguments explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you had a small logical mistake in there which @MartijnPieters already pointed out: The first argument of `super` should be the current class:

```
super(Worker, self).__init__()
```

In order to pass them to the superclass you need to accept these arguments in the subclass. Either by hardcoding:

```
class User(object):

    def __init__(self, id_code, name, surname):
        self.id_code = id_code
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

class Worker(User):

    def __init__(self, id_code, name, surname, username, password, worker_type): # changed
        super(Worker, self).__init__(id_code, name, surname) # changed
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.worker_type = worker_type
```

or using `*args` and `**kwargs` (see for example: [correct way to use super (argument passing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972866/correct-way-to-use-super-argument-passing)). But that's far from being trivial because you need to know which class needs which arguments and how the order should be and what arguments are positional-only or keyword-only or if you want to allow them all as positional-or-keyword-argument. Also you hide the argument(-names).

I would stick to hardcoding the arguments and only if that get's to complicated in the long run to consider switching to `*args, **kwargs`.