# Proper way of defining init() methods with different number of parameters (to be used in multiple inheritance)

Tags: python

**This is my current setup:**

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # ...other methods

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, dst, fname, alg, src=None):
       super().__init__()
       # I then use these instance variables throughout instance methods.
       self.src = [] if src is None else src
       self.dst = dst
       self.fname = fname
       self.alg = alg

    # ...other methods

class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, fname):
       super().__init__()
       # I then use these instance variables throughout instance methods.
       self.fname = fname

    # ...other methods

class C(A, B):
    """Here is my problem.
       When I try to inherit A and B this way,
       I keep getting those "missing required positional args..." errors
    """
    def __init__(self, dst, src=None):
       super().__init__()
       # I then use these instance variables throughout instance methods.
       self.fname = fname

    # ...other methods
```

**Here is what I am trying to do right now:**

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class A(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class B(Base):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

My main question:

What is the "best" (standard, most preferred, efficient, readable etc.) way to handle such situations?

P.S.

- I read the following article, [Python’s super() considered super!](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), but I could not derive the best answer for myself after reading it.
- Also, I referenced [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972866/correct-way-to-use-super-argument-passing) but the accepted answer does not have different number of params like I do...
- By the way, I am willing to hear that my design (class hierarchy) is bad overall. Technically, I could relocate methods that I am trying to inherit from A and B in C to the Base class...I hope (did not try yet)...

Comment: If `A` and `B` require such different signatures, with required positional arguments, should you even be inheriting `C` from both `A` and `B`? How do you expect users of the class to make sense of it and in what example does this make sense?

Comment: @Grismar good point I guess...like I mentioned, maybe my logic does not make sense. The reason why I wanted to inherit from A and B is because they both have some methods that I'd like to use in C. Should I just move out those common methods to the Base class?

Comment: can you share how you are using classes ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your implementation, to remove the error, I think it would be best to explicitly use the base class' required parameters based on the [method resolution order](https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2014/python-tutorial-understanding-python-mro-class-search-path) (in your case, the base class for the `class C` should be `class A`).

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, dst, src=None):
        fname = 'some value'
        super().__init__(dst, fname, alg)
```

This will be the simplest solution that can be done. But if you are willing to make design changes, I would recommend using composition instead of inheritance for python. I assume that you have methods in `class A` and `class B` that is needed by `class C`. With [composition](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/), needed functions/operations can just be added to the classes that needs it. It would also prevent code smells like [refused bequest](https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/refused-bequest)

Answer (score 0):

Python has an advantage that supports multiple inheritance, even the box office technology **java** doesn't supports this feature **because it leads to overriding of methods when both extended class have a same method name**.

But python overcomes this problem and supporting multiple inheritance.  To use multiple inheritance in python,  should know the arguments to define in proper way.

```
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, dst, src=None):
       super().__init__()
       self.fname = fname
```

In the above obove code,  Class **C** inherits Classes **A and B**.  Here first of all **super().__init__()** navigate to Class A, search for **.__init__()**,  if **init() or some other method abc()** not in Class A, then next it will look up into Class B,

These navigation go through based on sequential order that you inherits into Class C

Here Solution for you problem is,  you defined super class **__init__()** with parameters in both Class A & B, and calling super class **super().__init__()** with out parameters in Class C.