# What is the correct way of calling both superclass __init__ when they don't have same args?

Tags: python, inheritance, super

Assume I have two classes

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, v1, v2):
        self.v1 = v1
        self.v2 = v2

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v = 'something'
```

and a subclass that inherits both and needs to call both constructors (that have different arguments):

```py
class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self, v1, v2):
        # Is the following correct?
        A.__init__(self, v1, v2)
        B.__init__(self)
```

Is the above the correct way to do that? Or is there a way to exploit `super()` even when the `__init__` arguments of the superclasses do not match?

Comment: I believe this is why the recommendation is for all constructors to accept arbitrary keyword arguments.

Comment: I don't fully understand how that would solve this issue. Could you please provide me and example? Thank you very much

Comment: Change both constructors to take **kwargs and retrieve individual arguments from kwargs.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972866/correct-way-to-use-super-argument-passing.