# How to add driver options in Python Selenium under OOP structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have one `run.py` file that I execute:

```
from tasks.tasks import Task

with Task() as bot:
    bot.landing_page()
```

And this is the `Task.py` file:

```
from selenium import webdriver

import os


class Task(webdriver.Chrome):

    def __init__(self,
                 driver_path=r";C:\Selenium\drivers"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path

        super(Task, self).__init__()
        self.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.maximize_window()

    def landing_page(self):
        self.get('https://sampleurl.com')
```

I would like to add the following code but not particularly sure where and how:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add it to the super init function as a named var

```py
from selenium import webdriver

import os


class Task(webdriver.Chrome):

    def __init__(self,
                 driver_path=r";C:\Selenium\drivers"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path

        options = Options()
        options.add_argument('--incognito')
        options.add_argument('--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs')
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
        super(Task, self).__init__(options=options)
        self.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.maximize_window()

    def landing_page(self):
        self.get('https://sampleurl.com')
```

more info [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972866/correct-way-to-use-super-argument-passing)

Comment: Thank you so much this worked to my desired output. Will mark this reply as the answer once available