# Cast derived class to base class in python

Tags: python, casting, pydantic

I'm using pydantic models and would like to cast an object to its base class.
example:

```
Class A:
   a

Class B(A):
   b
```

got an instance x of type B which has both a and b fields, and I want it to be casted to type A, and be parsed accordingly.

the reason for this is that I'm getting some data from a service, but I need to pass half of it to another service, so I made 2 classes, one is a basic which has common fields to both incoming data and outgoing data, and the other for the extra fields which are incoming to my service.
I want to be able to cast between the incoming data to the outgoing data easily (like c++?), which means casting derived class data to base class data.

thanks!

Comment: There is no casting in Python. And you don't need it, either, because python is duck-typed. Just pass the object with attribute `b` to a function which expects an argument with attribute `b`.

Comment: so if i want to create type A from type B I need to manually write initialization for that?

Comment: what do you mean by "cast" **exactly**? That is a term with ambiguous meaning in a language like Python. Really, there is no such thing as *casting*. But sometimes it can informally just mean "create an object of another type from an object of this type", is that what you mean?

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You say you want it done "easily, like in c++", but in c++ you also need to do that manually, unless no conversion is actually needed (e.g. casting a pointer to the correct type), in which case you need to do nothing in python.

Comment: Check the answer to this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/77446717/4126114